# Segfault in glGenFramebuffers

Tags: c++, opengl, ubuntu, glew

I'm getting segfaults and can't figure out why.  The person I'm working with compiles and runs correctly on an OSX machine.  gdb backtrace gives me that it's coming from this section of code, specifically, from glGenFramebuffers:

```
    // Render the warped texture mapped triangles to framebuffer
GLuint myFBO;
GLuint myTexture;

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glGenTextures(1, &myTexture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, myTexture);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, size.width, size.height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE);

glGenFramebuffers(1, &myFBO);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, myFBO);
```

I'm running 12.04 Ubuntu with an Nvidia card using the latest proprietary drivers from Nvidia provided by the OS.  I'm not incredibly familiar with OpenGL, a lot of this code is my partner's, and he seems to be stumped as well.  If you need any further information, I'm happy to provide it.

Comment: Have you already checked for errors by calling `glGetError()` somewhere in your code? Maybe its output could help you.

Comment: Is the glGenFramebuffers pointer or function? If pointer - is it a valid (not NULL)? Is the OpenGL context created when you execute this code?

Answer (score 3):

The answer actually turned out to be really simple.  OSX coders don't need to call glewInit() before they start using glew calls - Linux and Windows users do.  Also, another bit of interesting information I found out:  Check if you're able to perform direct rendering using glxinfo.  It can make all the difference when running OpenGL programs.